# FullCalendar - will it work on a weebly page?

Tags: fullcalendar

I've been working on and looking for a solution to this for hours, so if this is easy, I'm really sorry.  But I'm stuck.  I love FullCalendar and it's exactly what I've been looking for, but I can't get it to work in our context on weebly.

I uploaded all the recommended css and js files from FullCalendar.  When you upload **files** through weebly, it automatically stores them in this directory: /files/theme/yourfile.jpg     I uploaded a sample html file to that directory, and it's working dandy.  You can see it here:
http://isuencounter.weebly.com/files/theme/gcal.html

When you create a **page** in weebly's structure, it stores the page in your root directory.  But when I put the identical code (only changed to point to the right directory) into one of my main pages, I get nada:
http://isuencounter.weebly.com/calendar-attempt.html

At first I thought I was pointing to the wrong place, but I've gone over it a bunch of times, and if you pull the source code on that second file, you'll see that all the links do actually bring up the code that they are supposed to.  Help?

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery is conflicting with some other script that you are using. The `$` synonym that jQuery uses might be used by something else.

Use `jQuery.noConflict()` at the beginning of your first `<script>` tag and replace all occurrences of $ with jQuery. For example:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      ...
    });
  });
```

I tried this by downloading your 2nd link and the calendar rendered fine. Let me know if this helps!